# Xcode build process stuck at "Copying swiftdocs"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoapods

[image]

Creating a build for my Xcode project takes too much time. It gets stuck at "Copying swiftdocs". I am making a build to run on device. I cant understand why this is happening. No relevant info available on internet. Just for the info, I am using Cocoa Pods in the project.

Is it anywhere related to pods? I am unable to run the app on device.

Comment: Can you try  Deleting "Derived Data" in the Organizer, and re-open and workspace.

Comment: @KetanP Tried just now. Didnt worked.

Comment: Please check I post answer. That may help you there are two solution for same.

Answer (score 1):

**Xcode** stuck indexing error (compiling model, copying swiftdocs, etc.)

1. Open your Project Folder.
2. Find ProjectName.xcodeproj file.
3. Right-Click Copy and Paste to Safe Place.
4. Right-Click Show Package Contents.
5. Find project.xcworkspace file and delete that file.
6. Reopen Your Project and clean and Rebuild.

If your problem is not solved then replace the file with your backup file.

Hope this will work for you. If still not restart your mac some time it works with restart.

Comment: As mentioned earlier I am using Cocoapods. I open the project using xcworkspace which is automatically created after installing the pods. Restarting the computer fixes the problem. But its not the ideal fix. However Thanks for your help.